# JSC_TYPE_MISMATCH warning in Google Closure Compiler

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler

I tried to use Google Closure Compiler, but in this code:

```
/**
 *
 * @constructor
 * @suppress {missingProperties}
 * @param {string} idOfTableContainer
 * @param {Array.<Object>} tableDataInJson
 */
function TableBuilder(idOfTableContainer, tableDataInJson) {
    "use strict";
    var idParser = new IdParser(idOfTableContainer, "row");

    /** @type {Array.<Object>} */
    var dataInJson = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(tableDataInJson));
}
```

I get this warning:

```
JSC_TYPE_MISMATCH: initializing variable
found   : *
required: (Array<(Object|null)>|null) at line 14 character 18
    var dataInJson = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(tableDataInJson));
                  ^
```

I don't understand what does it mean:

```
found   : *
```

Comment: The `*` stands for "any" type. It appears that, as far as Closure knows, `JSON.parse` returns a result of "any" type, and Closure cannot ensure that this will match the type declaration you have set on `dataInJson`.

Comment: Thanks, you can post it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `*` stands for "any" type. The warning says that as far as Closure knows, `JSON.parse` returns a result of "any" type, and Closure cannot ensure that this will match the type declaration you have set on `dataInJson`.